# How many paths could you make on a 3x3 grid?

Tags: combinatorics

Say you had a 3x3 grid, and could pick any square to start with.

[image: grid]

From that square, choose an adjacent or diagonal tile to move to, and draw an arrow to it. This is your new tile, and you can now either draw another arrow or stop here. You can touch as many tiles as you'd like, but you can only move to adjacent and diagonal tiles, and can only touch each tile once (once you touch a tile, you can not touch it again). If you drew an arrow every time you chose a new tile, how many different pathways would be possible on this grid? (The path doesn't have to touch every tile, and can end on the first tile chosen)

Comment: Have you attempted to work a little on this homework ?

Comment: It isn't homework, I was trying to figure it out because I wanted to use it to design a simple 2d gore system in a game. The enemies are squares, and are divided into a hidden 3x3 grid. The order that your cursor crosses the squares plays a preset gore animation. I wanted to know what the minimum amount of animations I would have to create to implement this system. So far, I'm thinking I limit it to 3 tiles (meaning the first 3 tiles touched by the mouse would determine the animation). I calculated that it would take 156 gore animations, but that is doable. Adding more tiles would be overkill.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. How did you get your number (156) ? By computer simulation ?

Comment: I drew a 3x3 grid, and manually drew out every possible path from any given square (crossing exactly 3 tiles every time). The center square had 24 pathways to take, the corners each had 14, and the last 4 tiles had 19 paths. I also calculated that crossing only 2 tiles would take only 40 animations, while one tile (a singular click on any tile) has 9 animations. Adding these 3 together, its actually 205 total animations, which is my bad.

Comment: The title asks a question, but you should make the problem statement in the body of the Question self-contained.  A clear criterion for what makes two paths distinct would be helpful, e.g. the sequence of labelled tiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is $10305$. You can do it using Python.

```
# 0  1  2
# 3  4  5
# 6  7  8
Neighbor = {0:{1, 3, 4},
            1:{0, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            2:{1, 4, 5},
            3:{0, 1, 4, 6, 7},
            4:{0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8},
            5:{1, 2, 4, 7, 8},
            6:{3, 4, 7},
            7:{3, 4, 5, 6, 8},
            8:{4, 5, 7}
            }

def search(nodes):
    # Input: A list of already-passed nodes
    # It must be the prefix of a path
    # This function calculates the number of paths starting with the nodes
    next_nodes = (set(range(9))-set(nodes)) & Neighbor[nodes[-1]]
    num_of_paths = 1
    for node in next_nodes: num_of_paths += search(nodes+[node])
    return num_of_paths

print(4*search([0])+4*search([1])+search([4]))
```